# PHP clean memory after using fopen()

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

When i use `fopen();` and then i use `fclose();` does it just close file or also cleans memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also cleans memory.

PHP does it by itself by the way (even without explicitely closing the pointer), using its own garbage collection functionality. It's still good practice to explicitely close it though.